# Is it possible to return normal polyline rather than flexible-polyline from here api routes endpoint?

Tags: here-api, here-routing

`flexible-polyline` algorithm provided here (https://github.com/heremaps/flexible-polyline) is not working properly on ios webview. I am wondering if there is a way to receive regular polyline via here routes api?

Answer (score 0):

The HERE Routing v7 API (in maintenance) is returning a regular polyline.

Here is the [API Reference](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/api-reference.html)

It seems there is no parameter to get a regular polyline with the Routing v8 API.